# How do I know what research I have already done?

Tags: civilization-5

I can't cross the ocean, but I can travel through seas. I want to know if I have done astronomy research or not (if it makes a difference, I am playing as Haroun al Rashid).

Answer (score 9):

Click the research tab (detailed view). Is in the top left of the screen if I remember it right (looks like a blue Erlenmeyer flask). There you can see the techs you have, tech that can be researched, eras, dependencies, you can create queues, etc.

The researched techs are colored cream-ish.

In the screen [image]

you can see that agriculture was researched, while pottery etc. can be researched.

Astronomy is in Renaissance era, on the top row if I remember it right, been a while :).

Comment: It's called an [Erlenmeyer flask](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erlenmeyer_flask).

Comment: You are right. That was the name I was looking for but since my last chemistry use was... about 15 years ago it was kind of erase from memory :). Edited answer.